# Obtaining an array element based on a random value

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

Suppose we have an array of 100 Strings, which you get them from R.string.xml.

```
private String lapi[]={"R.string.lapi0", "R.string.lapi1", "R.string.lapi2", "R.string.lapi3"..."R.string.lapi99};
```

Also we have a TextView and a Button:

```
pelicula=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lapicera);
btnElegir=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnElegir);
```

and we want that when we click the button get us a random value between 0 and 100:

```
int random=(int) Math.round(Math.random()*100);
```

The problem: what would be the easiest way to edit the TextView with the array value to which the random value belongs ?.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
pelicula.setText(getResources().getString(lapi[random]));
```

That is the most effective solution I thought, but doesn't work.

Do you know if there are other similar work as this way ?, without having to use a switch.

Sorry if my english isn't clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getString()` expects the resource id, you are just giving a String (even if it "corresponds" to the same textual id, it's just a String).

What you want to achieve can be done using [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (and you don't even need the array):

```
Random r = new Random();
...
int randomId = r.nextInt(100);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("lapi"+randomId, "string", getPackageName());
pelicula.setText(resID);
```

Be aware that it's more efficient to retrieve the resource with the id, as the doc states:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Comment: That's excelent! You're a genius! Thank you very much